Excel Macro needs autofill until reached empty cell, rather then static cell
I am building an excel macro that does many things. One of the steps is to write a formula in a new column and then autofill it down. When I do this the VBA says
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("G2:G39156")

but each month when I run this macro the data will have a different amount of rows. It works with my first set of data, but If I add a row then it won't function properly.
I first tried to simply change the range from 'G2:G39156' to 'G2:G100000' but this as I'm sure most of you guessed just gives me an error on every line after my data until row 100000.
The second thing I tried is within my formula I am creating, I added an if then statement to only calculate my formula if there is data in a cell, which looks like this:
ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(F2<>"",F2/E2,"")"
    Range("G2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("G2:G100000")

This will autofill all the way down to row 100000 but will remain blank if there is no data in the row. The problem is that I prefer not to have this blank cell with a formula in it from the end of my data to row 100000.

Normally the approach would be to find the last used cell. Btw, there's no need to use .AutoFill here. You can write the formula to the entire range in one step.

Important to note, a single macro that does "many things" may prove problematic in the long term.  You can call multiple subroutines from a single subroutine, so you can test and specify actions in each individual.  E.g., you want to create a dashboard, so have a subroutine to create the sheet, a subroutine to input headers, a subroutine to collect data, and a subroutine to format; each of those has a distinct and separate function which may need to be tested individually, so the breakdown will help you manage, create, and manipulate, over the lifecycle of the document(s).

Also - do your future self a huge favor and try to move away from the select/activate "macro recorder" way of writing VBA, and instead work directly with the object involved.  See  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba for useful guidance on that.  It will make your VBA more robust and easier to maintain.

From comments above:
Dim ws As Worksheet, lr As Long

Set ws = ActiveSheet 'for example

'use a column which will be populated for all rows
lr = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'assign formula in Col G
ws.Range("G2:G" & lr).Formula = "=IF(F2<>"""",F2/E2,"""")"

